# Как с помощью модуля auto-py-to-exe упаковать проект python в один файл вместе с картинками?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Нашел ответ, что для упаковки картинок нужно использовать данную функцию. Но я в упор не понимаю какое отношение эта функция имеет к интерфейсу auto-py-to-exe и как с её помощью упаковать картинки.

Упаковка без картинок и упаковка в папку работают без проблем. Вопрос именно в создании одного файла .exe с добавлением внешних изображений.

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

Comment: Вероятно потребуется установка библиотеки PyQt. Вам нужно создать файл ресурсов *.qrc (Можно собрать с помощью Qt Creator, он будет в формате my_res.qrc)
Скомпилировать его в my_res.py через терминал командой pyrcc5 -o my_res.py my_res.qrc
Подключить ресурс к основному файлу программы через import my_res
В основном файле программы пути к ресурсам нужно будет заменить на вид ':/my_img.png'
Ищите в этом направлении.

Comment: Решение сильно зависит от количества и использования картинок. Когда понадобилось запихнуть в проект пару-тройку иконок, я просто превратил их в байтовые константы в коде. Ну а если картинок много и больших, тогда разбирайтесь с предложенным @Павел

Comment: @AlexTitov можно подробнее? три маленькие иконки всего то нужно переделать. не делал такого раньше, гугл тоже не особо помог найти объяснение вашей формулировке

Comment: А на чем проект написан?  я знаю рецепт для `tkinter`

Comment: @AlexTitov Именно на нём. игру "сапер" делал, хочу иконки мин упаковать

Comment: 1. Получить байтовое представление иконки однострочной "программой" `print(open('icon_file.ico', 'rb').read())` .  2. Построить внутри прграммы представление изображения с помощью функции `PhotoImage` из `tkinter`, например: `img = PhotoImage(data=b'длинное полученное байтовое представление', format='png')`. 3. `img` использовать, где надо.

Comment: @AlexTitov хороший вариант, но я перед этим еще импортирую `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` и меняю размеры меняю через `boom_icon = Image.open('Boom.png').resize((_icon_size, _icon_size))`, чтобы вручную этим не заниматься. там нет возможности открыть файл в режиме `rb`, только `r`. а то что получилось загоняю в `img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(boom_icon)`. не знаете вариант изменения размера, чтобы не возвращался объект `PIL`, который уже нельзя перевести в байтовый вид? я и сам в эту сторону теперь копаю, но может у вас есть готовое простое решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо **Alex** **Titov** за наводку на байтовые константы. В моём случае нужно было еще изменить размер картинок, так что использовал библиотеку `io` в дополнение к его варианту. С её помощью после изменения размера смог получить длиннющую строку отображения новой картинки в байтовом виде. Далее эту строку сохранил в новую константу, а все остальные строки удалил. Константу уже можно использовать в `PhotoImage` для присвоения виджетам.

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

icon = Image.open('icon.png', mode='r').resize((42, 42)).crop()  # 42 - требуемый размер
icon_arr = BytesIO()
icon.save(icon_arr, format='PNG')
icon_arr = icon_arr.getvalue()
print(icon_arr)  # <- скопировал результат из консоли в новую переменную byte_icon

byte_icon = b'...'  # <- тут длинная строка в байтовом виде. Весь код выше можно удалять.
                    # Кроме "from tkinter import PhotoImage", так как он еще нужен ниже
final_img = PhotoImage(data=byte_icon, format='png')
```

В итоге в `auto-py-to-exe` не пришлось добавлять дополнительные файлы и все нормально собралось в один файл `.exe`